# Getting attribute value from view object

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a custom `View` object, and I only have access to the `View`.
So, I have an attribute called `attribute1` and I have set it for my view using `app:attribute1="value"` how can I retrive the `attribute` value from just my `View` object, is this even possible? what approches can I take for this?
I have searched almost everywhere and couldn't find anything about it.

Example:

```
CustomView customView = new CustomView();
```

I would like to get the attribute value from `customView`

Comment: Your edit actually makes me have more questions. If you're just constructing an "empty" instance of your view with `new CustomView()`, then why do you expect it to be associated with an xml attribute?

Comment: @BenP. was just showing an example ofc, I'm inflating it.

Comment: Then I recommend editing again to show exactly how you're trying to use it, because the question as it is currently written is quite confusing.

Comment: I don't know how it's confusing to you, I just have `CustomView customView` and I want to get attribute from that `instance` I don't know why you need extra info? I can just access `customView` thats all I am saying I dont need to know how I create it or stuff. Can I access attributes from just `customView` or not?\

Comment: It 100% matters. Take `TextView` for example. It has (among others) two constructors: `TextView(Context)` and `TextView(Context, AttributeSet)`. The second one is used when inflating from XML, and the first one is not. If you call the first one from Java, it will have nothing to do with a layout file or any layout attributes. Anyway, you can see my answer below: there's no way to magically access attributes unless the object provides a method to do so.

Comment: Yeah you see, I am not talking about the inner class. I just want to know if I can access the attributeset from just my instance. No need all this extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attributes are available inside `AttributeSet` objects, which are only available inside the `View`'s constructors.

Therefore, if you cannot modify the source of the custom `View` class, you cannot accomplish what you're looking to do.

If you *can* modify the source of the class, then you can save a reference to the attribute value inside the constructor, and provide a getter method for it. For example:

```
private int strokeColor;

public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, 0, 0);
    this.strokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.MyCustomView_strokeColor, defaultColor);
    ...
    a.recycle();
}

public int getStrokeColor() {
    return strokeColor;
}
```

Comment: Can't really access the custom view class but I will mark this as accepted since there isn't a way to get attributeset from my instance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is official documentation how to do, exactly what you want.](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr) All you need is `declare-styleable`, where you could create your custom attribute for view. Then inside view, in constructor you retrive a values.

Comment: Please read the question, I have a `Custom View` object and I need to access attribute values from it.

Comment: Create inside your CustomView, method like `getAttribute1()` which will return value.

Comment: I can't do that, I am asking is there a way to do it with just the `CustomView` object?

Comment: What do you mean `CustomView` object? Instance of your custom object? Edit your post, show some code example.

Comment: Edited, I can't access the inner view.